# Passing javascript data with laravel controller

Tags: jquery, controller, laravel, routes, laravel-3

I have a page with 3 jquery ui tabs. Now when I'm redirecting from a specific controller method within laravel I want to redirect back to my page containing the ui tabs and return to the second ui tab instead of the default first one.

```
$(function() {
    $("#tabs").tabs({ active: 1 });
});
```

This is the way I set it to the second tab in a static manner, this loads on every page. Now how can I redirect to a route with 1 as my javascript variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps you can use the Session laravel method. Then you can set `active: {{ Session::get('tab_index') }}`, for example. Only works for blade templates (`templateName.blade.php`)

Comment: Thanks for reminding me of this. Redirecting to my routes with tab index values now. And setting them on my masterpage with: var tab_index = "<?php echo Session::get('tab_index'); ?>"; Work perfectly now. Thank you!